# How to change text beside its checkbox without any tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div style="float:left; min-width: 20%; ">
    <input id="Select All" class="search_init checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" value="Select All" name="EnquiryType" />Select All
    <br />
    <input id="Extra Works" class="search_init checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" value="Extra Works" name="EnquiryType" />Extra Works
    <br />
</div>
```

Now I want font weight to bold of checkbox's text. It would be like **Select All** and **Extra Works**

Please keep in mind you don't have to right any tag on the text.
You can use checkbox Ids only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you kept space in the id?

Comment: @rohit : bro it is auto generated code i cannot edit its ids as wel

Comment: ID's are invalid to use by jQuery

Comment: I know you don't /have/ to add any tags, but the label tag is everyone's friend.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced in front end development, but I believe you can have something called "CSS Style sheets".

With these style sheets you can explicitly state that for any input tag, you want a certain type of style.

I highly recommend learning about style sheets at:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

They provide great examples and may help you not only for this, but for the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'font-weight' to div. See this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="float:left; min-width: 20%;font-weight:900">
    <input id="Select All" class="search_init checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" value="Select All" name="EnquiryType" />Select All
    <br />
    <input id="Extra Works" class="search_init checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" value="Extra Works" name="EnquiryType" />Extra Works
    <br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div style="float:left; min-width: 20%;font-weight: bold; ">
```